# How to deserialise Xml content to string

Tags: c#, serialization, xmlserializer, deserialization

I'm using an XmlSerializer to deserialise a configuration file.  I want to be able to fetch the child content of an Xml element into a string field.  This child content can be xml itself.

A simple example:

```
public class Configuration
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string MyAttribute { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to parse the following:

```
<Configuration MyAttribute="foo">
    <SomeOtherXml />
</Configuration>
```

I want the Content property to be set to `"<SomeOtherXml />"` but I can't seem to get this to work.  I don't want to encapsulate the content inside a CDATA or similar.

Is this possible or do I need to manually handle the parsing of my configuration file?

Thanks

Comment: You could use a Regex to parse it, but I'm guessing you already knew that.

Comment: @Duncan - Why do you care what the xml element is called.  You could simply name the Content property to "SomeOtherXml" if you wanted.

Comment: @Ramhound - I don't care what the Xml element is called - I want the **value** of the Content property to be `"<SomeOtherXml />"`.

Comment: To explain the reasoning - I want to embed an XSL transformation within a configuration file, but still allow intellisense to work when writing the XSL.  If I encapsulate the XSL data inside a CDATA then I lose the intellisense.  As a workaround I am manually parsing the configuration file.

Comment: @Duncan - The XML code you posted is that what your code currently generates or what you want your code to generate?  My confusion is that you have the Content property but didn't actually tell is what the xml file currently looks like.

Comment: why can't you use a Content property of type `XmlElement` ? That would solve your problem. As `string` it will always be escaped.

Comment: @BrokenGlass That seems to work if I move the Xml I want to parse into a child node, thanks muchly :) How do I mark the Content property to be the content of the Configuration node rather than the content of a Content node?

Comment: I ended up encapsulating the Xml content within a CDATA element as the parser was reading in my newline entities (&#xa;) in the contained Xsl which I didn't want it to do and went back to standard deserialisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use the XmlSerializer but does require manual parsing so it may not be worth it in the end.

There may be other and better ways to do this, but the way I found to do this is to have your Configuration class implement the [IXmlSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx) interface.

```
public class Configuration : IXmlSerializable
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string MyAttribute { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        if(reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element &&
           string.Equals("Configuration", reader.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            MyAttribute = reader["MyAttribute"];
        }

        if(reader.Read() &&
           reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element &&
           string.Equals("SomeOtherXml", reader.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            Content = reader.ReadOUterXml();  //Content = "<SomeOtherXml />"
        }
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer) { }
    public XmlSchema GetSchema() { }
}
```

Hope this helps.